# Finding where a pair of numbers are located in a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists e.g

```
[["text",[6,24,4,40],[12,6,11,10],[...]]]
```

I would like to be able to find out the position of a pair of numbers e.g [4,40] but I only need the position of where it is in the overall list so in this case it would be 0 (excluding the position of "text"). I.e. For this example I want to know the position of list [6,24,4,40]?
So far I can only manage to do it with 1 number, not a pair of numbers.

Comment: Could you please show the code you wrote, explain what part is giving you problems, show any error messages you are getting. Or even any outputs from your code that might help us help you. Please read this to get the most out of SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I used something else that I grabbed off this site e.g to find where the number 4 is:     a=4    print[(i, x.index(a)) for i, x in enumerate(list) if a in x]  which gives the output [(0,2)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def subfind(needle, haystack):
    """Returns index if found, None otherwise."""
    length = len(needle)
    index = 0
    for item in haystack:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            for ee in xrange(0, len(item) - length + 1):
                if item[ee:ee+length] == needle:
                   return index
            index += 1
```

Comment: Thanks John...so in this case needle would be [4,40] and haystack be the list [[6,24,4,40,],[12,6,11,10]]?  and what does the length in your code refer to? The length of this list?

Comment: @weaselsnak: that's right.  I added the missing `length`.

Comment: John I've run the function with subfind([4,40],[[6,24,4,40],[12,6,11,10]]) and used 2 as the length or len(haystack) but it doesn't display anything. Just wondering what I'm doing wrong? As I take it the index/indices are meant to be returned. I imagine I am putting in the wrong length or something.

Comment: @weaselsnak: 12 minutes ago I edited the code.  If you use the current version and call it like you did, you should get `0`.